# How many times does baryogenesis happen during the history of the universe?

Tags: cosmology, baryogenesis

Does the baryogenesis happen both in GUT epoch and electroweak Epoch during the history of the universe? If yes, are there any differences during this two times?

Comment: As far as i am aware they constitute two independent baryogenesis theories. So one theory predicts the baryogenesis in the GUT epoch while another possibility is the baryogenesis during the electroweak epoch.

Comment: Most theories involve the GUT epoch where X and Y bosons exchange quarks with leptons.

Comment: Baryogenesis, i.e. the excess of baryons over antibaryons, is not modeled with a unique model.  It is still under research, and a long story for the answer format here. Have a look at this http://physics.ucsc.edu/~joel/Cosmology224/Lectures/08_224-L18-Baryogenesis.pdf  . It will all depend on the model, if a single cause or multiple ones are included.

Comment: @Jaywalker Thank you very much for pointing out that these baryogenesis in different epochs are from different theories. So there are of course some models that take these two baryogenesis into account simutaneously. Right?

Comment: @LawrenceB.Crowell It sounds like baryogenesis via leptongenesis, as Sphaleron process in electroweak theory?

Comment: @annav Thank you very much for the information you provided. They help a lot.